# Does sql server for linux support udf's written in C#?

Tags: sql-server

I guess the question is in the title. I'm wondering if I can use udf's written in C# and run them against the linux version of sql server. Are there any limitations for this?

Comment: Yes, but assemblies must be SAFE.

Comment: @DanGuzman what does it mean to be safe?

Comment: `Permission_Set = SAFE` assemblies are described in the [CREATE ASSEMBLY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-assembly-transact-sql) documentation. Basically they cannot access external resources like environment variables, files, network, registry, etc., they can only be self-contained code operating on inputs supplied through SQL Server parameters.